# Class 'ImageFile' has no 'FromString' member when compiling a proto file

Tags: grpc

I am new to grpc and I have written this proto file.

```
syntax = "proto3";

message ImageFile {
    bytes value = 1;
}

service Edgedetect {
    rpc DetectEdge(ImageFile) returns (ImageFile) {}
}
```

I managed to compile the pb2 and pb2_grpc files in the same directory usind the command

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I. --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. test.proto
```

I am having trouble in test_pb2_grpc.py file in the response deserializer line

```
self.DetectEdge = channel.unary_unary(
    '/Edgedetect/DetectEdge',
    request_serializer=test__pb2.ImageFile.SerializeToString,
    response_deserializer=test__pb2.ImageFile.FromString,
    )
```

and in another line where FromString method is called on the ImageFile

```
def add_EdgedetectServicer_to_server(servicer, server):
  rpc_method_handlers = {
      'DetectEdge': grpc.unary_unary_rpc_method_handler(
          servicer.DetectEdge,
          request_deserializer=test__pb2.ImageFile.FromString,
          response_serializer=test__pb2.ImageFile.SerializeToString,
      ),
  }
```

saying that

```
Class 'ImageFile' has no 'FromString' member
```

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to execute the your code? I personally have seen this problem in code editor, and it is due to the editor unable to parse or include the generated files. If you don't like the stuck error hint in your editor, restarting it may solve this problem.

If the problem still exist, please post more details about what gRPC versions you are using, and how to reproduce it.

Comment: I found it most likely to be the problem of editor in vscode. I had to port the code to another server and run it and it is working correctly.